# Upload file type with FMElfinder browser on symfony

Tags: symfony, elfinder

I have successfully integrated FMElfinderBundle with IvoryCkeditor. Thanks to provider.

Now, I am looking for to upload the files for `<input type="file">`
from the same elfinder browser through symfony as,

`$builder->add('file', 'file');`

Is it possible to upload file from Elfinder file browser for this case?

**Updates:**

My config for elfinder looks like this,

```
fm_elfinder:
    instances:
        default:
            locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
            editor: ckeditor # other options are tinymce, tinymce4, form, custom and simple
            fullscreen: true # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
            theme: smoothness # jquery theme
            include_assets: true # disable if you want to handle loading of the javascript and css assets yourself
            connector:
                debug: false # defaults to false
                roots:       # at least one root must be defined
                    uploads:
                        show_hidden: false # defaults to false
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads
                        upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 2M
        form:
            locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
            editor: form # other choices are tinymce or simple, and form
            fullscreen: true # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
            include_assets: true # disable if you want to handle loading of the javascript and css assets yourself
            connector:
                debug: false # defaults to false
                roots:       # at least one root must be defined
                    uploads:
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads
                        upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                        upload_deny: ['all']
                        upload_max_size: 2M
```

and on my form type for elfinder form type,

```
->add('image','elfinder', array('instance'=>'form', 'enable'=>true))
```

What I get on my output is just a text field with no popup on clicks, what's the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bundle provides it's own form type for this cases.
[Elfinder form type](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle#elfinder-form-type), btw usage of input file type, in my opinion assumes that you will handle file uploading process by your own controller

Comment: I have tried using Elfinder form type also but it gives me text field, but I want to upload image which I think is possible from file type only. Is there any way for that or, how can I do that with the controller?

Comment: Indeed, elfinder form type gives you just a simple text field. By clicking on it, it will pop-up elfinder window, where you can manage files (and upload of files of course).

Comment: Ok, see my updates and check if there are any things I am missing.

Comment: May be you forget to include jQuery lib on your page? The configuration for the form type looks ok.

Comment: It works fine with the ckeditor browse, should I add library separately for form type?

Comment: Thanks @helios . It now works, just including jquery library on top solves the issue. But the elfinder browser only loads when I run the symfony using `php app/console server:run` and with xampp it pops up only blank page. Is there any issue with that or fix?

Comment: Blank page usually opens, when cache is not warmed, try clearing it with ./app/console cache:clear. And if you in prod env, add --env=prod param

Comment: I have tried clearing cache and re-installing assets but nothing has worked for me...

Comment: Try opening developer panel in chrome/firefox and look at network tab, and find which assets are not loaded.

Comment: I forget to check for that, thanks man my assets path was not configured and by default it looks for root of localhost and after configuring assets path (prefix), it works fine.